# Does there exist an invertible matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that $A+A^{-1}= O_2$?

Tags: matrices

Does there exist an invertible matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that $A+A^{-1}= O_2$? Why, or why not?

Comment: Hint: This is the same as $A^2 = -I$.  Geometrically, multiplication by $-I$ is the same as a 180-degree rotation...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there exists such a matrix. Why? Because

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

For another example,

$$\begin{pmatrix}7 & -5 \\ 10 & -7\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}-7 & 5 \\ -10 & 7\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be too hard to find all examples.

If we consider
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then we want $-A=A^{-1}$, but we have formulas for both, so what we want is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-a & -b\\
-c & -d
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{ad-bc}
\begin{pmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Looking at the off-diagonal elements we can conclude that $ad-bc=1$. And then looking at the other two elements we can conclude that $a=-d$. That gives a restriction on the product $bc$, but we can choose $b$ freely from $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. So we have a bijection from the set of matrices with that property to $\mathbb R\times(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: Do you mean "looking at the off-diagonal elements", to conclude $ad-bc=1$?

Comment: Edited. Thanks Erick.

Answer (score 1):

If $A + A^{-1} = O_2$, then $A^2 + I_2 = O_2$ and, thus, $A^2 = - I_2$. Assuming that $A$ is diagonalizable, let $A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}$ be the eigendecomposition of $A$. From $A^2 = - I_2$, we obtain $Q (\Lambda^2 + I_2) Q^{-1} = O_2$ and, thus, $\Lambda^2 = - I_2$. Hence, the spectrum of $A$ is $\{\pm i\}$. Which diagonalizable matrices have purely imaginary eigenvalues?

Comment: can you elaborate  how we obtain the third row: Q (\Lambda^2 + I_2) Q^{-1} = O_2 pls @Rodrigo de Zevedo

Comment: @SamSk If $A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}$, then $A^2 = Q \Lambda Q^{-1} Q \Lambda Q^{-1} = Q \Lambda^2 Q^{-1}$. Also, $I_2 = Q Q^{-1}$. Hence, $A^2 + I_2 = O_2$ becomes $Q \Lambda^2 Q^{-1} +  Q Q^{-1} = Q (\Lambda^2 + I_2 ) Q^{-1} = O_2$.